# what is the algorithm details of "AdaboostRegression" in machine learning fields?

Tags: scikit-learn, adaboost

I have search much for this question, including "adaboost" paper which only explains "AdaboostClassifier" method; Now I want to code "AdaboostRegression" in Python and I can't find the exact details for coding. I also check 'sklearn' about this method, but I can't find the detail which maybe hides in 'sklearn';
so shall I get more information about it?

Comment: The question does lack detail and e.g. including information on the data set would be cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find details in the [`AdaBoostRegressor`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/d300f406aeeac439b4212558f208ce5a9613a1d5/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py) class.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note, whilst for decision trees and random forests Sci-kit learn are cool (which is why you are interested in Adaboost), it isn't great at performing neural networks in contrast to e.g. Tensorflow etc...